# Getting error 800cce05 - when using cdosys.dll

Tags: iis, windows-10, asp-classic, cdo.message

I'm getting the error:

```
cdo.message.1 error 800cce05 The requested body part was not found in this message
```

when the page gets to the 2nd line of the code:

```
set objMail=createobject("CDO.Message")
objMail.From="email"
ObjMail.To="email"
ObjMail.Subject= "Hello"
ObjMail.TextBody="some text"            
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _       
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="my smtp provider" 
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _         ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")="my username"
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")="my password" 
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
ObjMail.Send
set objMail=Nothing
```

This code is OK and running on other machines, one is exactly the same as on windows 10.

Please advise how to resolve this error.

Comment: Do you have smtp installed on the Windows 10 machine?

Comment: Yes. I have. The problem solved by reinstall windows and iis